# QOS on ubuntu server

Tags: qos, tc

I want to run the following script on ubuntu server. eth1 is NAT interface, and eth2 is the WAN interface which has a static public ip:

```
TCA="tc class add dev eth2"
TFA="tc filter add dev eth2"
TQA="tc qdisc add dev eth2"
SFQ="sfq perturb 10"
tc qdisc del dev eth2 root
tc qdisc add dev eth2 root handle 1: htb
tc class add dev eth2 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 4560kbit
$TCA parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 2280kbit ceil 4560kbit prio 0
$TCA parent 1:1 classid 1:11 htb rate 912kbit ceil 4560kbit prio 1
$TCA parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 912kbit ceil 4560kbit prio 2
$TCA parent 1:1 classid 1:13 htb rate 10kbit ceil 10kbit prio 4
$TQA parent 1:10 handle 10: $SFQ
$TQA parent 1:11 handle 11: $SFQ
$TQA parent 1:12 handle 12: $SFQ
$TQA parent 1:13 handle 13: $SFQ
$TFA parent 1:0 prio 0 protocol ip handle 10 fw flowid 1:10
$TFA parent 1:0 prio 1 protocol ip handle 11 fw flowid 1:11
$TFA parent 1:0 prio 2 protocol ip handle 12 fw flowid 1:12
$TFA parent 1:0 prio 4 protocol ip handle 13 fw flowid 1:13
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --sport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 10
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --sport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 11
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --sport 995 -j MARK --set-mark 12
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --sport 1024:65535 -j MARK --set-mark 13
TCAU="tc class add dev imq0"
TFAU="tc filter add dev imq0"
TQAU="tc qdisc add dev imq0"
modprobe imq
modprobe ipt_IMQ
ip link set imq0 up
tc qdisc del dev imq0 root
tc qdisc add dev imq0 root handle 1: htb
tc class add dev imq0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 4560kbit
$TCAU parent 1:1 classid 1:13 htb rate 10kbit ceil 10kbit prio 4
$TQAU parent 1:13 handle 13: $SFQ
$TFAU parent 1:0 prio 4 protocol ip handle 13 fw flowid 1:13
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1024:65535 -j MARK --set-mark 13
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j IMQ --todev 0
```

When I do `modprobe imq` and `modprobe ipt_IMQ` I get the error `kernel module is not found`. Is there any way I can make this script work on ubuntu server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should patch your kernel to add support for IMQ. Here you find the patches http://www.linuximq.net/patches.html and here you will find details instructions how to compile it: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1404537

Regards

Comment: Only now I saw fab responded faster than me:) In essence is the same answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is not out of the box solution in Ubuntu. You have to recompile your kernel with the imq patch applied. There are a lot of tutorials on how to do that. Here is the first I have found: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1404537

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the ifb device is the successor to imq. I'm very new to imq/ifb queing, but I believe they can be used in the same way as each other. You can load the ifb module by running `sudo modprobe ifb`.
Also, I came across this:
"There is the also IMQ patch, but it is not recommended. The IMQ design is unsafe and ifb is better" (from http://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg49306.html).

Comment: Thanks, the module exists in the ubuntu version I use. You saved me from taking up the risky task of compiling the kernel.

Comment: IFB and IMQ are quite different. IMQ filtering happens after packets went through netfilter (and that can be quite useful in some cases), that's not the case in IFB.